# Problems with CURL performance

Tags: php, performance, curl

for example i will take site http://fs.to.

Here is screenshot from chrome console panel:
[image: chrome console]

We can see that it takes 289 ms to load html document.

Then i have this code:

```
<?php
$time1 = microtime(true);

    $ref = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1500);
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://fs.to');
    $html = curl_exec($ref);

echo microtime(true) - $time1;

?>
```

it outputs 0.64 (640 ms)
Why it so slow and how can i speed it up? (2 times slower)

Comment: I'm not sure you can :X

Comment: `.30394` from a virtualbox on my setup, so there can be a lot of variance in simple timings like this.... you'll probably find quite a variance in your own timing if you run it several times in succession

Comment: @MarkBaker but i request this page from 1 computer. Logically i need to see approximately the same timings, but not 2 times slower

Comment: Have you run your curl test multiple times to see what variance there really is? Is it 2x slower every time if you run your test 10 times?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, sure. I ran it more than 10 times. it always from 0.56 to 0.7 second.
But in browser console it always from 0.21 to 0.3 second

Comment: Was chrome running on the machine as the PHP code? From the same network?

Comment: @symcbean yes, from same machine and same network

Comment: The next thing I'd look at is the TCP/IP traffic - using wireshark or similar, see if there's anything different between the 2 clients (maybe curl is waiting for a keepalive connection to close or doing a full shutdown handshake).